# How to send servlet response to web.xml configured error page

Tags: tomcat, servlets, custom-error-pages

I am using Tomcat. I defined some `<error-page>` in `web.xml` and mapped `404` error to page `/error/error.jsp`. I need to detect if the resource exist and set the response status to 404 if the resource is not available.

```
response.setStatus(404);
```

But Tomcat does not redirect to the 404 page I defined, so my question is, is there any API to get the page location defined in `web.xml`? I don't want to parse the `web.xml` by myself.

Comment: perhaps provide some more information so that we can solve the problem itself. Because knowing the error page might not help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use [`HttpServletResponse#sendError()`](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html#sendError%28int%29) with a [status code](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html#field_summary). E.g.

```
File resource = new File(path, name);
if (!resource.exists()) {
    response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_NOT_FOUND); // Sends 404.
    return;
}
```

The servletcontainer will then display the suitable errorpage.

Note: the `return` statement isn't there for decoration. It will avoid that the remant of the code in the same method block will continue to run and might produce `IllegalStateException`s in the appserver logs! Starters namely often think that methods like `sendRedirect()`, `forward()`, `sendError()`, etc somehow automagically exits the method block when invoked. This is thus *not* true ;)

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no API.  The setting is internal to Tomcat, it doesn't expose this to the outside world directly.  (You can, as you said, parse the web.xml - since it's XML it would be simple to write an XQuery to pull this out).

Also I think you seem to be confused as to exactly how this is supposed to work.  You supply a URI to Tomcat that it will use to serve the HTML body of a 404 response.  It will need to be able to resolve this URI into an actual resource just as if it were supplied in a request.  So in many cases, you don't need a servlet to detect if the resource exists - **you need a servlet to contain the resource to be served**.  The exception being if you use Tomcat to serve static filesystem data for some URLs, which I believe is possible albeit seldom used.

If you have a Tomcat set up without any servlets, what are you expecting it to serve anyway?  Where on earth are you expecting it to get your `error.jsp` page from?  How do you expect it to know that?  What you need to do is add at least one servlet to Tomcat (containing the `error.jsp` file), and then make sure that web.xml maps the `/error/error.jsp` URL to this servlet (and that the resource is positioned in the error subdirectory in the servlet).

Once this is done, you should be able to manually go to e.g. `http://localhost:8080/<context>/error/error.jsp` and have the response served (possibly with some weird content since there's no actual exception but the file should be found).  Similarly, if you've set up the error-page directive correctly in web.xml, going to an umapped URL (e.g. `http://localhost:8080/<context>/asdfghjasgh`) should show you your error page as the 404 response.

Comment: thanks for your answer, i know the question seemed a little odd, i am designing a framework, the servlet is actually dispatching request to suitable action.